# Why can't I build the temple of Fervus?

Tags: warlock-master-arcane

Fervus has given me a quest to build a temple, which I want to do because I like Fervus' spells. I even have a holy ground open next to my city and a free pop with which to start construction.

But I'm not allowed to build a temple to Fervus. In fact, no such temple is visible in the building list. I can build a temple to Krolm, Lunron or Krypta. Temple to Dauros is greyed out. Where are the rest of the temples?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've discovered the problem: The race of my city. I also note that none of the gods whose temples I can build are opposed. I was able to build a temple to Fervus in a Monsters city.

ETA: I've seen a holy ground for each kind of city. Humans get the most religious flexibility, being able to build a temple to any deity except Grumgog. Undead and Monsters divide the complete pantheon between them in opposing sets. Hence, Grumgog is Monster exclusive.

Here's the list of temples, for reference:

- Humans

  - Dauros
  - Helia
  - Krolm
  - Krypta
  - Fervus
  - Lunord
  - Agrela
- Undead

  - Dauros
  - Krolm
  - Krypta
  - Lunord
- Monster

  - Helia
  - Fervus
  - Grumgog
  - Agrela

Answer (score 0):

Just as an aside - if you capture an existing city it seems to retain it's prior race alignment.  You need to destroy it and then settle the relevant race there to be able to build the associated temples...took me a while and a bit of frustration to figure that out